# How do I create two fields where whichever is filled first will auto-populate the other?

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join, inventory-management

I manage facilities for a large complex and am responsible for issuing and tracking physical keys for our clients here. Keys are printed with specific codes (which match the lock itself), and I have also numbered individual doors on a separate system, to account for the fact that locks often change doors.

In my database I am building in Microsoft Access (sorry, very much a SQL noob), I have a table for spaces (which includes building, room and door numbers), and another separate table for keys (key code, key notch code, master keys, etc.). I also have included a field in the spaces table that references the keys table (via the ID field) to indicate which locks are associated with which doors.

Lastly, I have a log table where I record requests from clients for keys. They may request keys by door number or key code. I want to be able to enter in either the door number or the key code in a form (tied to a query which pulls from both tables) and have it automatically populate the other field accordingly. Presently, I managed a configuration where entering the door number would auto-complete the key field, but I cannot get it to work vise-versa.

This may require some kind of structural change, but I am willing to even delve into directly writing SQL code if needed. I even tried my hand at writing INNER JOIN code, but it was already doing a double-join, and I'm not sure if that is something that can be chained.

Halp!

Comment: This calls for VBA coding.

Comment: Or maybe not. Maybe just need two comboboxes BOUND to the same field. Each combobox displays different text alias but both save the same ID value.

Comment: This sounds promising, but can you expound on implementation? I have struggled to fully grasp the controls for binding and aliases and such. I have made some meager progress in this area, but having something like this would really help clarify (even if it doesn't fix this specific problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding some VBA in the AfterUpdate event of the textbox fields.  You can use the same query in each case.

For argument's sake, I'll call the door number textbox "txtDoorNbr", and the key code textbox "txtKeyCode".

First, write a query that pulls all door numbers and key codes.  I think you stated that you already have this query written.

Next, in the AfterUpdate event of txtDoorNbr, you would write something like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select KeyCode from MyQuery where DoorNumber = " & Me.txtDoorNbr & "")

Me.txtKeyCode = Rec(0)

rec.Close
db.Close
```

In the AfterUpdate event of txtKeyCode, write something very similar:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select DoorNbr from MyQuery where KeyCode = " & Me.txtKeyCode & "")

Me.txtDoorNbr = Rec(0)

rec.Close
db.Close
```

That should do it.  Might need to tweak it a bit to account for certain conditions (i.e. an error message if no corresponding record is found in the query, etc...) as well as the actual field names you use in your query, but that's basically the approach.

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening in the last statement, "Me.txtDoorNbr = Rec(0)"?  I can tell you are setting the value to Rec(0), but I am unfamiliar with "Rec" (which I presume is different from "rec").  Additionally, is the 0 an array index?  How is this targeting the current record?  Sorry, again: Noob.

Comment: Typo.  Shoulda been rec(0).  Basically, it's the value in the first cell in the recordset "rec", which should only return either the DoorNbr or KeyCode, depending on which one is run.

Answer (score 0):

You have a form for entry of log record? This is simply data entry to a new record, right? What data is input - date, keyID, userID? So form is bound to the Log table and controls with ControlSource set to each field so input is saved directly to record in table?

My suggestion is to have 2 comboboxes. One is set up to display the door number and one set up to display the key code but both have ControlSource set to the key field and will save keyID. This is a non-conventional design. Users will have to learn that if they make selection with one combobox they can ignore the other. You could put a label above the two comboboxes "Select door number or key code."

Door combobox RowSource like: `SELECT keyID, DoorNum FROM ...;"`
Key combobox RowSource like: `SELECT keyID, KeyCode FROM ...;`

For both comboboxes set properties:
ControlSource: the key field in Log table
ColumnCount: 2
ColumnWidths: 0";1"